# How to pass an integer as input parameter in asm custom instruction in?

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, riscv

I am trying to run an assembly code for my own custom instruction.

The code is as below

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main() {
  uint64_t x = 123, y = 456, z = 0, a=22;
  int i;

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  asm volatile ("custom0 x0, %0, %[i], 0" : : "r"(i),[i]"r"(i));
  printf("The value of i is:- %d \n",i);
  asm volatile ("custom0 %0, x0, %[i], 1" : "=r"(z) :[i]"r"(i));
  printf("The value of z %d is:- %d \n",i,z);
}

}
```

So basically the custom0 instruction as shown above works like as shown below.

```
//             opcode
//             |               address
//             |               |
//             |               |       
asm volatile ("custom0 x0, %0, 1, 0" : : "r"(i));//for moving i to address 1
asm volatile ("custom0 %0, x0, 1, 1" : "=r"(z));//for moving contents of address 1 to z.
```

The instruction works fine standalone, but when i try to parameterise the address field and run in a for loop the data is not moved into that address.

the output of the above program is

```
The value of i is:- 0 
The value of z 0 is:- 0 
The value of i is:- 1 
The value of z 1 is:- 0 
The value of i is:- 2 
The value of z 2 is:- 0 
The value of i is:- 3 
The value of z 3 is:- 0
```

As you can see the value of i is correct but the value of z is always zero.

Instruction set being used is the RISCV ISA:- http://riscv.org/download.html#tab_spec_user_isa

Comment: I also tried using basic int. didnt work

Comment: What is your compiler? You should check "Constraints for asm Operands" section of compiler of your arch (basic constraints for gcc are here - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints) I'm not sure that you "address" field" will have "r" constraint. You can also want to check asm output of your compiler (with -S option) and assembler manual.

Comment: I'm using the riscv newlib compiler based on GCC 4.8

Comment: Ravi, I see no custom0 format in isa, how it is encoded? How it is parsed by assembler? Do you use any tutorial with example of custom-0 usage or implementation?

Comment: The Riscv processor has a set of custom opcodes, defined in the below file you can see the format here https://github.com/riscv/riscv-opcodes/blob/master/opcodes-custom

Comment: Which format use your custom-0? How it was implemented? If address is imm, I think you should use not "r" constraint but "i".

Comment: i tried using constant i, but the compilation failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93937/discussion-between-prashant-ravi-and-osgx).

Answer (score 1):

`asm volatile ("custom0 x0, %0, %[i], 0" : : "r"(i),[i]"r"(i));`

As I understand, `@custom0` instruction (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-opcodes/blob/master/opcodes-custom) get only 2 registers as first and second argument; third argument is "imm12" = immediate. So, there is a way to assembler to encode x0 register and %0 (which will be register), but imm field should have "i" (immediate) constraint, not "r" (register) - check gcc doc on constraints: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints

Immediate field should be encoded into the command by assembler, it is part of command binary encoding. You have no any legal variant to encode runtime variable inside the binary code of your program, so you can't pass `int i` as `"i"` asm argument. `"i"` argument accepts **only compile-time constants**.

You may rewrite code as 4 asm statements without loop with "i" and constant value

```
asm volatile ("custom0 x0, %0, %1, 0" : : "r"(i), "i"(0));
asm volatile ("custom0 x0, %0, %1, 0" : : "r"(i), "i"(1));
asm volatile ("custom0 x0, %0, %1, 0" : : "r"(i), "i"(2));
asm volatile ("custom0 x0, %0, %1, 0" : : "r"(i), "i"(3));
```